# java 8 lambda tech question for jsonpath library

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, spring-test

I'm looking info about lambda although I'm not able to find something similar to below function. It belongs to *class org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers* , and *ResultMatcher* is a @FunctionalInterface, and result is type *MvcResult* and jsonPathHelper.doesNotExist return void

```
public ResultMatcher doesNotExist() {
    return result -> jsonPathHelper.doesNotExist(getContent(result));
}
```

I call above one through

```
jsonPath("$._embedded" ).doesNotExist()
```

I have literally no idea about:

1. if jsonPathHelper.doesNotExist return void then why doesNotExist return ResultMatcher.
2. Class has anything similar to **result**, where is this argument come from?

Thanks

Comment: it's unclear to me what you're asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda in your code:

```
result -> jsonPathHelper.doesNotExist(getContent(result));
```

is just a representation of a `ResultMatcher` since its a `FunctionalInterface`. You can look at it as if :

```
public ResultMatcher doesNotExist() {
    return new ResultMatcher() {
        @Override
        public void match(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
            jsonPathHelper.doesNotExist(getContent(result)); // returns void
        }
    };
}
```

> if jsonPathHelper.doesNotExist return void then why doesNotExist
>   return ResultMatcher

Your method `doesNotExist`, just returns the functional interface in itself, which can thereafter be used to invoke its `match` function. Note that invocation would also be returning `void`.

> Class has anything similar to result, where is this argument come
>   from?

If you look at the anonymous class above, with lambda representation the `result` becomes the argument of the `match` method within the `ResultMatcher` implementation.

So when you actually wish to access this implementation(or `ResultMatcher` in general), you would invoke the method as follows(simplified initializations):

```
ResultMatcher resultMatcher =  doesNotExist(); // your method returns here
MvcResult result = new MvcResult(); // some MvcResult object
resultMatcher.match(result); // actual invocation
```

Comment: thanks @nullpointer. I edited my question due to typo error on my second question. btw, do you know any resources talking about this? cheers

Comment: @RafaelRuizTabares updated the answer. hope that helps.